# Insert Excel dates values in database date field

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, date, parsing

I have date values on an excel sheet in the dd/mm/yyyy format. Initially I catch those values as text (.Range(A2).Text)
Obviously the insert statement fails since the date values do not display in the mm/dd/yyyy format.
I have tried parsing the date values and assign them to a date variable but the Insert statement still failed. .net displays the date like that: #mm/dd/yyyy#. Is it the hash tag that generates the issue?
If I parse and then pass back to another string variable the value still displays in the dd/mm/yyyy format.
How can I get string values in the mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: Where is your code? You would simply insert a date as a date. Why would you ever want to convert a date to a string and then parse back to a date?

Comment: Does your database column expect a string or a datetime?  If you're really dealing with dates and times, it should be a DateTime (or DateTime2) type field.  You should then parse your date from the Excel sheet and insert.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway My database field is 'date', so only mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: But you will have to use a DateTime variable in VB.Net and parse your string to that.  Then use a parameterized query to update the database table's Date column

Comment: `I catch those values as text (.Range(A2).Text) ` - You better have adequate string validation in place. `Range.Text` returns the as-displayed format text.  If the column width is not sufficient, you get `####`.  Best to use the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in SQL Server are stored in a neutral, binary format.  When you insert a row in SQL Server, best practices say to use yyyymmdd, as in:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(MyDate) VALUES ('20180801')
```

By default, SQL will parse the string (in the values clause above) according to the current locale settings.  That is why the above, ISO format is preferred since it is unambiguous.

Comment: Better is to use a DateTime (or DateTime2) column and a parameterized query.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway you don't like the date type?  Why is that?  (The OP is only talking about dates)

Comment: The Date type is fine, but the advice is the same.  Use a parameterized query.  Then you don't need to worry about formats (since a Date column has no format).